# Buttons in ion-footer-bar are overlapping

Tags: css, safari, ionic-framework

I am try to use Ionic `ion-footer-bar` to show three fixed buttons and unlimited other scrolling buttons:

[image]

However, the fixed icons are overlapping each other, in Safari. The code is on: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ohho/pen/oXwWKB)

How can I have the blue buttons layout properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, don't know if this will suffice, but one thing you could do is add this to your CSS:

```
.buttons button{
    margin-right:2px;
}
```

Here is the updated Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doRROV

**edit:**
Also, I played with resizing your Codepen, and it seems if you put this additional CSS rule, it will not overlap once the window is resized:

```
.buttons{
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

Updated CSS is in the same Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doRROV

Now, I don't know how will this behave on your device though - you may want to calculate the width and then set that min-width accordingly.